# UITableviewCell with Vertical Separator between detail and Text

Tags: uitableview

I am working on a custom app which needs to display cells similar to the iPhone address book with a vertical line between the detail label and the text - this can be seen when you choose edit mode from the contacts app.

Is there a simple way of doing this?  UITableViewCellStyleValue2 is 90% of what I need, but I was wondering if there is a simple CALayer call which will do one side of a label.

Thank you for any help.

Rich

Comment: use UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as customizing your UITableViewCell doesn't fit in the preset styles, you should go on subclassing. Even if it is for a single line between the two labels.

That can look as a PITA at first but trust me, that will save you (and your team) big time in the long run.

And UITableView and UITableViewCell are everywhere in iOS app. The faster you are at subclassing cells the better.

[Apple doc on UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)

Enjoy :)